# Mongo aggregate query to skip empty params in `$match`

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo aggregate query in which I pass variables `$device_name` and `$device_type`

```
db.getCollection('devices').aggregate([
{ "$match" : {
    "name" : "$device_name",
    "deviceType": "$device_type"
  }
}]);
```

However as part of user request either of the variables `$device_name` or `$device_type` can be empty. I want to skip the match corresponding to the variable which is empty. 
Example: If request only has `$device_type` then query should only match for `deviceType` param and skip check for `name`.

I know we can use `filters` for this but I need to use aggregator query for this due to environment restrictions.
I tried using `$and`, `$ifNull` but I failed to get desired result.

Comment: You can simply make a check using if else for it. What is the issue?

Comment: @Ashh can you please suggest how? I am not much familiar with mongo aggregations

Comment: Which language you are using?

Comment: @Ashh I have to create aggregate query in above way only so can use pipeling operators only.

Comment: Hey @PrashantShubham! Have you fixed this issue ? I am in need of this solution. If so please update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the variables before assigning them into a match query

```
let condition = {};
if(device_name != '')
condition.name = device_name;
if(device_type != '')
condition.deviceType = $device_type;
```

And then pass the dynamic condition to match
db.getCollection('devices').aggregate([{ "$match" : condition }]);

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
db.getCollection('devices').aggregate([
{ "$match" : {
    $or: [ 
      {"name": $device_name },
      {"deviceType": $device_type }
       ] 
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work in case of both fields empty it will return nothing, also if both are specified it should match on both params i.e `and` query